# Files and drives

Tags: filesystems, backup, macos

[image]

##I am using Macos high Sierra 10.13.6

I used (select ) the second disk (disk1s2) for backup on timemachine by mistake, then I unselected it then delete it the  time machine file on the image of the disk, unfortunaltelly I have a lot of used giga bit remained in others and most of that space is free, but i don't know how to get it back to its normal before i used it on the time-machine

Any clew ??

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I am using MacOs 10.13.6 High Sierra